# C Insert image to ms sql database using odbc

Tags: c, sql-server, odbc

Is there any way to put image into MS SQL database on c? The table field type is "Image", i have `HBITMAP` in my program, how can i put it into database?
I use `SQLExecDirect()` function to insert text into VARCHAR fields, but i also need to work with "Image" field. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using ODBC.

If you take a look at this article: [Using ODBC with Microsoft SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx)
and scroll down to the very bottom, there is a sample app code ("Putimage.c"), using `SQLExecDirect()` function.

Comment: Checked out this article. Still can't figure out how to put my HBITMAP into db. There is an UCHAR Data[] array of chars in the example, not image :(